# Significance of the pulse setting on stepper driver and performance

Tags: pwm, frequency, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I have a stepper motor driver [DM860D](http://cncdrive.com/datasheets/DM860D.pdf) and I am using signals from an Arduino to control a NEMA 23 stepper motor.

Can someone explain what the significance of the pulse/rev setting on the driver is, or point me to the appropriate resources for the same? Is it related to performance?

Comment: You have a microstepping driver. The native steps/rev of your motor is probably 200. That is 200 steps for 1 revolution of the motor shaft. With microstepping you can increase the number of steps per rev as per the table printed in the driver. What effect on performance? With higher step/rev, your system needs to generate more step pulses per second for a given speed. If you’re doing cnc, you might be more concerned about resolution rather than speed. You get to choose the tradeoff. With the current setting, set that to suit the motor. Too high and the motor will get too hot.

Comment: microstepping, or full stepping, if too high, slow/heavy motor couldn't follow, so miss steps, or just get stuck trembling.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108429/understanding-the-relationship-of-pulse-and-stepper-rpm here is a link to what may answer your Q.